# Override method is not getting called in Kotlin

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, fragment, overriding

I am using the Textwatcher in my base fragment i override the implemented methods in the child fragment super methods are called and the override meathod in the child fragment is not getting called.

Base Fragment

```
open fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
open fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
open fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

protected class TextChangeListener() : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        val fragment = BaseFragment()
        fragment?.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after)
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val fragment = BaseFragment()
        fragment?.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count)
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        val fragment = BaseFragment()
        fragment?.afterTextChanged(s)
    }
}
```

Child Fragment

```
mBinding!!.goalsBody.addTextChangedListener(TextChangeListener())

 override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        saveMenuItem!!.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mBinding!!.goalsBody.text.toString()))
    }
```

Comment: Why are those `TextChangeListener` functions creating new instances of `BaseFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of code that you haven't shown us, but I think what you wanted to do in `TextChangeListener` is:

```
override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    this@BaseFragment.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after)
}
```

And similarly for the other two functions.

And for this to work you also need to declare `TextChangeListener` as [an `inner` class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes):

```
protected inner class TextChangeListener() : TextWatcher {
```